# PowerShell unexpectedly adds "CN=" prefix to computer name

Tags: powershell, active-directory, wmic

I am trying to iterate through a list of computers and retrieve the model of each one. When I print out the name of each computer using Write-Output, it is what I expect (just the name). However when I try to get the model using a wmic command, it seems to be using "CN=$name". And even if I do .Substring(3) it is still throwing error "Alias not found" and shows "CN=$name". Here is my script:

```
$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter '*'

foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    Write-Output $computer.Name # Outputs how I expect, just the name
    wmic /node:$computer.Name csproduct get name | Write-Output # Throws error, alias not found CN=$name
}
```

Comment: Change `/node:$computer.Name` to `/node:($computer.Name)`. The name property is being completely ignored in your example. The node parameter is expecting a string. It is essentially doing "$computer.name", which results in the value of the first property. In your case, that is the DN.

Comment: @AdminOfThings Great minds think alike :) I figured that out at almost the same time. It stumped me for a moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
wmic /node:$computer.Name csproduct get name
```

PowerShell only thinks that `$computer` is the variable that should be expanded. So it does a `ToString()` on `$computer`, which comes out to the full distinguished name of the computer (which is why trimming the `CN=` from the beginning isn't helpful). You can see this if you output this:

```
Write-Output "$computer.Name"
```

You'll see that you get the distinguished name appended with `.Name`.

To avoid this, you can explicitly tell it that you want `$computer.Name` to be resolved by enclosing it with `$( )`:

```
wmic /node:$($computer.Name) csproduct get name
```

There's some more reading about this here if you'd like: [Variable expansion in strings and here-strings](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/variable-expansion-in-strings-and-here-strings/)